# Toast weird appearance

Tags: android, android-toast

Can any one help me with my `Toast` appearance? Why `Toast` text is floating out of its boundaries? Here is my code...

```
   Toast.makeText(this, "My Toaster", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[image: iamge]

Comment: Have you used any themes or styles in your app?

Comment: @ParindaRajapaksha i am using Theme 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'

Comment: check how toast custom position reacts, if it works then there might be theme problem i guess

Comment: issue Resolve by just removing the following line from theme
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>